# How to compare between a git branch and a local folder that isnt a branch

Tags: git

Ok, someone got a copy of code from the master branch via zip file, made some changes and now wants to merge this back in and I'm being asked to do this.  Regardless of my objections to this being done, I can

- create a new local branch from master
- copy/paste this "changed" code over the top my of the code in my local branch
  Is there a better way?
  When I do this, way more folders and files are marked as different, mainly due to issues dealing with linefeeds etc. 
  eg. warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ...file-name-here

Comment: That's the right way. You can either deal with the whitespace better or just paste the _actually_ changed files.

Comment: Even when you're zipping the  code and extracting it , you would have the git configs right? Did you tried git status on the extracted code?

Comment: @Sam, no when you download a zip of the branch from Azure devops, that folder is just that a folder of code